# Music Player in Java?

Tags: java, mp3

I have Code Which plays a mp3 file java.

The issue that I encounter was that,

--> The audio output was only heard when program ran under the debug mode with breakpoints, but not under Run mode.

What could be the possible way counter this issue? I have attached the code for better understanding.

```
 FileInputStream mp3_file=new FileInputStream("xyz.mp3");
 Player mp3=new Player(mp3_file);
 mp3.play();
 System.out.println("Over");
```

Comment: So what happens when you *do* just run it? Does the app close immediately? I suspect the `Player.play()` method just *starts* it playing, rather than blocking until the track is finished.

Comment: After Sometime, Console output is "Over", with no audio output...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have faced same issue in my one of the project. I have used for loop. It solve my problem.

```
FileInputStream mp3_file=new FileInputStream("xyz.mp3");
Player mp3=new Player(mp3_file);
 for(int i=0;i<=3; i++)
     mp3.play();

System.out.println("Over");
```

But If create executable jar file of your code and run it, it works fine..... ;)

Answer (score 1):

Probably your program ends before the music has finished. Make sure that your program doesn't end until the music has finished. For example:

```
mp3.play();
System.out.println("Press Enter to stop");
System.in.read();  // wait until user presses Enter
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your program is just exiting because the code in the `main` method is finished very quickly.

We don't know what is your `Player` but I think it is playing music on a different thread than main thread, so as long as your code stops, it works fine.

In the `main` method, you should stop execution of code. For that, simply you can read something from console using:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
...
// here we will get input and program won't quit until we press Return
new Scanner(System.in).readLine();
```

In addition to that, you can use something like

```
try{Thread.sleep(Long.MAX_VALUE);} catch(Exception e){}
```

to sleep main thread and wait too much time.

Answer (score 0):

Threading with a waitFor() directive might be the way to go.  That also could give you the ability to have a separate thread for the control interface that allows you to interrupt or pause.